# Как правильно сделать загрузку изображений на сервер чрез пароль?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать обработчик загрузки изображения через пароль неполучается

```
    $pass = "1q2w";
$login = "boyko";
if(@$_POST['result'] != $pass){ 

  if (!move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "../foto/" . $login . ".jpg"))
    {
    chmod("../foto/" . $login . ".jpg", 0644);
    $contentcenter .= '<img  src="../foto/' . $login . '.jpg" align="center" width="100" border="0">';
    chmod($uploadDir, 0755);
    }
    else
    {$contentcenter .= '<img src="../foto/' . $login . '.jpg"  align="center" width="100" border="0">';}    


}


<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
<input name="userfile" type="file"  class="textfield"/>
<input type="text" name="result" size="30" class="textfield" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: не грузится изображение, несрабатывает пароль

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if(@$_POST['result'] != $pass){

Сейчас с неправильным паролем должен загружать, если верить это строчке.

Comment: как это правильно сделать?

Comment: @ПетроБойко наверное исправить логический знак на `===`